# Warm start of the Gurobi solver

Tags: matlab, gurobi

I am using Gurobi to solve a quadratic problem with bilinear equality constrains in MATLAB. I want to provide a feaible initial guess x0 for the non-convex optimization, but I couldn't find a way to do that. How can i input a warm start to Gurobi? I checked online document and can only find warm start for MIP and LP problems